# bot framework returning unauthorized after server reboot

Tags: iis, botframework, unauthorized

I have my bot. it's online. on a local machine the bot is working fine, but on the server it is returning unauthorized error. These are the iis logs

```
2016-12-30 23:06:44 104.168.146.32 POST /rbots/mybot/api/messages - 443 - 40.78.21.180 BF-Facebook+(Microsoft-BotFramework/3.1++https://botframework.com/ua) - 401 0 0 93
2016-12-30 23:06:44 104.168.146.32 POST /rbots/mybot/api/messages - 443 - 40.121.93.134 BF-Facebook+(Microsoft-BotFramework/3.1++https://botframework.com/ua) - 401 0 0 187
2016-12-30 23:06:45 104.168.146.32 POST /rbots/mybot/api/messages - 443 - 40.127.183.46 BF-Facebook+(Microsoft-BotFramework/3.1++https://botframework.com/ua) - 401 0 0 374
2016-12-30 23:06:45 104.168.146.32 POST /rbots/mybot/api/messages - 443 - 40.121.88.101 BF-Facebook+(Microsoft-BotFramework/3.1++https://botframework.com/ua) - 401 0 0 187
2016-12-30 23:06:45 104.168.146.32 POST /rbots/mybot/api/messages - 443 - 40.127.183.46 BF-Facebook+(Microsoft-BotFramework/3.1++https://botframework.com/ua) - 401 0 0 374
2016-12-30 23:06:45 104.168.146.32 POST /rbots/mybot/api/messages - 443 - 40.127.183.64 BF-Facebook+(Microsoft-BotFramework/3.1++https://botframework.com/ua) - 401 0 0 375
2016-12-30 23:06:47 104.168.146.32 POST /rbots/mybot/api/messages - 443 - 40.121.93.134 BF-Facebook+(Microsoft-BotFramework/3.1++https://botframework.com/ua) - 401 0 0 187
2016-12-30 23:06:47 104.168.146.32 POST /rbots/mybot/api/messages - 443 - 40.121.93.134 BF-Facebook+(Microsoft-BotFramework/3.1++https://botframework.com/ua) - 401 0 0 187
2016-12-30 23:06:47 104.168.146.32 POST /rbots/mybot/api/messages - 443 - 40.127.183.64 BF-Facebook+(Microsoft-BotFramework/3.1++https://botframework.com/ua) - 401 0 0 374
2016-12-30 23:06:47 104.168.146.32 POST /rbots/mybot/api/messages - 443 - 40.121.92.251 BF-Facebook+(Microsoft-BotFramework/3.1++https://botframework.com/ua) - 401 0 0 187
2016-12-30 23:06:48 104.168.146.32 POST /rbots/mybot/api/messages - 443 - 40.127.183.46 BF-Facebook+(Microsoft-BotFramework/3.1++https://botframework.com/ua) - 401 0 0 390
2016-12-30 23:06:48 104.168.146.32 POST /rbots/mybot/api/messages - 443 - 40.121.91.106 BF-Facebook+(Microsoft-BotFramework/3.1++https://botframework.com/ua) - 401 0 0 187
2016-12-30 23:06:48 104.168.146.32 POST /rbots/mybot/api/messages - 443 - 40.121.93.134 BF-Facebook+(Microsoft-BotFramework/3.1++https://botframework.com/ua) - 401 0 0 187
2016-12-30 23:06:48 104.168.146.32 POST /rbots/mybot/api/messages - 443 - 40.78.17.157 BF-Facebook+(Microsoft-BotFramework/3.1++https://botframework.com/ua) - 401 0 0 78
```

we didn't do anything to the bot; however, suddenly it stopped working after the reboot. I gave full permission to the folder that's containing the bot, but still not working.

Comment: Is it hosted on Azure? Is not working on any channel or just on Facebook channel? Does the Test Button on the bot framework dev portal report an error?

Comment: its not hosted on azure , its not working on any other channels , the test button returns only "unauthorized"

Comment: Where is hosted then? Are u sure the bot id, key, etc are correct on your Web config?

Comment: its hosted in a vps hosting company , yes..we got a very huge load on the server so we asked the hosting company to expand it  , they increased the RAM and CPU and then it stopped working with this error...all of our bots stopped at the same time we have 3 bots running

Comment: are u using ngrok?

Comment: I used it now , when I sent a message it returned two respones

get /  404    not found
get /    200 ok

Comment: any solution please ?

Comment: It's not clear how it's your infrastructure at this point? If your bot is hosted locally; is it exposed to the internet? What URL do you have configured in the dev bot framework portal? Maybe the bot it's not accessible anymore from the internet.

Comment: my infrastructure is on hostwinds vps , and the bot is accessible from outside, I can open the api/messages page. the url configured in the bot framework is the hostwinds vps . I dont know what to do to be honest , I dont know what setting to check because it was working perfectly and suddenly it stopped

Comment: This happens sometimes when the bot don’t handle ServiceUrl trust properly.

If this is what’s happening, the fix is: (for C#)
1) Make sure the BotAuthentication attribute is specified on the controller
2) If the ServiceUrl is stored, call MicrosoftAppCredentials.IsTrustedServiceUrl to extract whether the URL is trusted
3) Later, when rehydrating, call MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(url) if the URL was trusted per the prior call

Comment: the attribute is there , and the code is unreachable . The authentication fails and it doesnt continue , it looks to me some IIS problem because 3 bots stopped running at the same time..

Comment: Any solution for this issue? I am really stuck

Comment: Mazen - I'm on the BF team and tried to reach out to you, but it looks like the email address associated with your bot registration is invalid.  Can you correct it?

Comment: Also, you should take a look at the Auth troubleshooting guide here:  https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/support/troubleshooting-bot-framework-authentication/

Comment: Hi @MazenAbuTaweelih, the first step is to establish whether your bot is sending authorization headers to our server. I suspect not, but we should confirm. Can you follow Step 5 in the document that Lars linked above? If your bot is indeed omitting headers, we will need to inspect your bot's logic to understand why they're being dropped.

Comment: Dear Dan ,  Thanks for your support. Everything was working fine locally on the emulator but on the server it was always giving unauthorized. Anyway , the issue wasnt fixed and we are dropping the server in days as we went to a new machine , If your team wants to take logs from the server please let me know as I replied to the email that was sent , the issue started to affect our business so we had to move to another server.